# How can i change slider's maximum value according to another slider

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am using matlab gui and i would like to change slider's maximum value (slider2) according to another slider's value (slider1).
My formula is simple. But i don't know how to change slider value. Here is my slider codes:

```
taper = get(hObject,'value') ; %slider 1
set(handles.texttaper,'string',num2str(taper)) ;
guidata(hObject,handles) ;
```

```
rs = get(hObject,'value') ; %slider 2
set(handles.textrs,'string',num2str(rs)) ;
guidata(hObject,handles) ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change slider2's max value by slider1 you have to set the slider2 `'Max'` value in the callback function of slider1. I made you a small example:

```matlab
% --- Executes on slider1 movement.
function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

set(handles.slider2,'Max',get(hObject,'Value'))   %This line does the magic!!


% This function creates slider 1
function slider1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

set(hObject,'Min',0,'Max',10)

if isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor',[.9 .9 .9]);
end

% --- Executes on slider2 movement.
function slider2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

set(handles.text2,'string',get(hObject,'Value'))

% This function creates slider 2
function slider2_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

if isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor',[.9 .9 .9]);
end

% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function text2_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

I create two sliders. Slider1 has a range between 0 and 10. Its callback function sets the `'Max'` value of slider2. Slider2's value is shown in the textbox.

Hope it helps!